# How to pipe to ffmpeg RGB value 10?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, pipe

I am trying to create a video file using ffmpeg. I have all the RGB pixel data for each frame, and following [this](https://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2017/02/12/a-simple-way-to-read-and-write-audio-and-video-files-in-c-using-ffmpeg-part-2-video/) blogpost I have code which sends the data frame by frame via a pipe. And it works mostly. However if any pixel has a value of 10 in any of the 3 channels (e.g. #00000A, #0AFFFF, etc) then it produces these errors:

```
[rawvideo @ 0000020c3787f040] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 170) 
pipe:: corrupt input packet in stream 0
[rawvideo @ 0000020c3789f100] Invalid buffer size, packet size 32768 < expected frame_size 49152
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
```

And the output video is garbled.
Now I suspect because 10 in ASCII is newline character, that this is confusing the pipe somehow.
What exactly is happening here and how do I fix it so that I can use RGB values like #00000a?

Below is the C code which is an example of this

```c
    #include <stdio.h>

    unsigned char frame[128][128][3];

    int main() {
    
        int x, y, i;
        FILE *pipeout = popen("ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -s 128x128 -r 24 -i - -f mp4 -q:v 1 -an -vcodec mpeg4 output.mp4", "w");
    
        for (i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
            for (x = 0; x < 128; ++x) {
                for (y = 0; y < 128; ++y) {
                    frame[y][x][0] = 0;
                    frame[y][x][1] = 0;
                    frame[y][x][2] = 10;
                } 
            }
            fwrite(frame, 1, 128*128*3, pipeout);
        } 
    
        fflush(pipeout);
        pclose(pipeout);
        return 0;
    }
```

EDIT: for clarity, I am using Windows

Comment: Are you using windows? Consider opening with `"wb" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried your code in Linux and it worked for me. I think @Craig Estey suggestion is probably the answer.

If it doesn't work, you could try to write the data using `write` instead of `fwrite`, if available. (I've had issues writing binary data to pipes using `fread/fwrite` family of functions in the past.)

So you could try changing this line:

```
fwrite(frame, 1, 128*128*3, pipeout);
```

To something like:

```
int fd = fileno(pipeout);
write(fd, frame, sizeof(frame));
```

And also remove the following line:

```
fflush(pipeout);
```

EDIT: There is some troubleshooting tips on the comment section of the blog post you linked. Specially regarding the Windows version of this program.